# Mock a service after a particular execution in a test case

Tags: java, junit4, wiremock

Consider the scenario as below :

In a service -

```
public method M1() {
   daoCall();
   thirdPartyServiceCall();
}
```

I am trying to write a test case for M1. I am preparing a mock for third party service using WireMock.

```
testM1() {
   prepareMockForThirdPartyService();
   service.M1()
}
```

What I am looking for is there any way in Java to mention in testM1() to execute the prepareMockForThirdPartyService() call after the daoCall() in method M1()?

OR

I am using a Util for thirdPartyServiceCall(). Can I do something in testM1 such that it will execute the prepareMockForThirdPartyService() call after Java loads the Util.

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding
 @Before
 public void setup() {
//Write your logic to be called before the test method
}
Before will be called prior to your test method

Comment: Similaly your can use @After where you can write the DAO call after the test method

Comment: My concern is not to prepare the mock service before the testM1, but in between the execution of M1 method. after the daoCall and before thirdPartyServiceCall. I need some info after having the dao call to mock the third part service.

Comment: It might help if you explain what it is you're trying to achieve with your test - what you're trying to do isn't achievable as is, but we might be able to help come up with an alternative

Comment: sounds like you need two unit tests then. one to test that the dao call functions properly, and one that tests the service call which uses the mock service with static data that you pretend came from the dao.

Comment: Yes Stephan even I also thought the same .We need to write normal java code which will call a method one after the other or we need to use priority for test cases in this case.But Priority is not a suggested way Dheeraj

Comment: @Pradeep
Here is my case - 
in daoCall I am inserting a record into database. Then I get the id generated for that record.
The same id should be used to make a third party service call. The id is a mandatory requirement for the third party. 
So I am writing a test case for M1 which does all the work for me. But I am not getting how to mock the third party service with the id that is generated in daoCall. I hope I have tried better to explain my concern

Comment: Can you please paste the method call what you are making in src file with the id .We need to know the access modifier of that method .Based on that we can visualize